# How to convert a vector of digits into an integer?

Tags: vector, common-lisp, type-conversion

For several mathematical fun problems I am using vectors of digits as a representaion of integers. This works fine for me so far. Now I want to convert the vector back to an integer. I did not find anything suitable out-of-the-box and came up with the following function:

```
(defun vector->integer (vec)
  "Returns a given vector of digits as an integer."
  (loop :for digit :across vec
        :with number-string = ""
        :do (setf number-string
          (concatenate 'string number-string (write-to-string digit)))
        :finally (return (parse-integer number-string))))
```

It basically does what I want but I found the conversion `vector` to `string` to `integer` a bit cumbersome. Is there anything more efficient?

Comment: This question is about code efficiency, you should post it on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As @TeMPOral answered my question already, I will not asked again on _codereview_ but will think about it the next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use multiplication instead of concatenating strings?

E.g.

```
(loop for digit across vec
      with number = 0
      do (setf number (+ (* 10 number) digit))
      finally (return number))
```

Or even simpler:

```
(reduce (lambda (a b) (+ (* 10 a) b)) vec)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is simpler and more efficiently written as:

```
(defun vector->integer (vector)
  (parse-integer (map 'string #'digit-char vector)))
```

Comment: That is indeed very concisely coded but also needs a conversion from 'vector' to 'string' to 'integer'. Isn't this inefficient?

Comment: @MartinBuchmann: one string and one integer. Your code creates strings concatenating a string with a single character string. It also does that in a LOOP. Which is inefficient. Let's say the vector has 100 digits. Your code creates strings with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 98, 99, 100 length. Only the last one is kept. All the others are garbage. My code creates only one string of the same length as the input vector, given that the implementation of MAP is half decent.

Comment: @MartinBuchman: if you concatenate something to the end of a list or a vector in a loop, then it is easy to see that this will be inefficient. Generally concatenating vectors in a loop is not efficient. Usually one can write more efficient code in relatively simple way. It's also often possible to write more efficient code, but then the code might look more complicated.

Comment: My code is definitely worse, that was not my point. I meant in comparison with the multiplication solution by TeMPoral. Anyway, thanks again for sharing your experience.

Comment: @MartinBuchmann: That's true. That's why I wrote that your code (reading the number from a constructed string) is written more efficiently this way. The code from TeMPoral uses a different approach.